# When should I use fputs instead of fprintf?

Tags: c, printf, fputs

What exactly is the difference between the two?

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but did you check the documentation for the [two](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)  [functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fputs.html)?  One does formatted output, the other outputs a string, unformatted, to the stream.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What does your handy C reference manual say?

Comment: `fputs(s, f)` is functionally equivalent to `fprintf(f, "%s", s)`.  They both compile to the same code (a call to `fputs`) with modern optimizing compilers.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/) does formatted output. That is, it reads and interprets a
format string that you supply and writes to the output stream the
results.

[fputs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fputs/) simply writes the string you supply it to the indicated output
stream.

`fputs()` doesn't have to parse the input string to figure out that all you want to do is print a string.`fprintf()` allows you to format at the time of outputting.

Comment: I may be wrong but fputs is safer if you wanted to print a string controlled by user. There are a lot of posts on StackOverflow talking about that.

Answer (score 15):

As have been pointed out by other commenters (and as it's obvious from the docs) the great difference is that `printf` allows formatting  of arguments.

Perhaps you are asking if the functions are equivalent where no additional arguments are passed to `printf()`? Well, they are not.

```
   char * str;
   FILE * stream;
   ...
   fputs(str,stream);    // this is NOT the same as the following line
   fprintf(stream,str);  // this is probably wrong
```

The second is probably wrong, because the string argument to `fprintf()` is a still a formating string: if it has a '%' character it will be interpreted as a formatting specifier.

The functionally equivalent (but less direct/efficient/nice) form would be

```
   fprintf(stream,"%s", str);
```

Answer (score 5):

Uhm...
...`puts()` just writes a string, while `printf()` has a number of formatting facilities for several types of data.

`fputs()`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fputs/

`fprintf()`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/

Documentation is useful! Learn to read it, and you'll have a powerful tool on your side.

Comment: `puts` / `printf` is not an exact correlation to `fputs` / `fprintf`. `puts` appends a `'\n'` to its output, unlike any of the other functions.